# Honda Civic 2004 - Airbag Error code

Tags: honda, civic, supplemental-restraint-system

My 2004 Honda Civic Coupe Manual Transmission has it's airbag light constantly on.
Honda just did a recall on them for the Takata airbag issue about 3 months ago.

I learned how to get the error code from: http://forums.clubrsx.com/showthread.php?t=636707

And to me it looks like the error code is 2-3, but that doesn't exist in their form.

Here is the video of the error code: https://goo.gl/photos/SU2TdFcFbtFYNxzW6

Maybe someone can tell me if I read it incorrectly.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see an error code, too blurry.  perhaps you should goto your local auto parts store and have them scan your car for error codes.  You will get a specific code and follow up with an action item.  It should be pretty explicit.  They will scan your car for free in hopes of selling you some parts.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Most auto parts stores won't scan for airbags or ABS because their scan tool is too basic and cannot read these. To the OP: you can try a parts store, but you'd be better off just buying one yourself and reading the codes. This will give you the exact cause of the SRS failure instead of guessing. Just ensure if you do, you get one which can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read that flash pattern as 3-2. Three longs and two shorts.  If that is correct the code is for "Increased resistance in the drivers seat belt tensioner" This is a explosive bolt in the seat belt reel that allows a spring to tighten the seat belt.

This is a part that make me nervous to work on. When triggered, these go off with quite a bang.

To my knowledge this is not involved in the Takata airbag inflater recall.

Comment: Ahh yes most definitely 3-2... Not sure how I messed that up! Thanks.